# Creating view on receiving a message

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a MVVM view and viewmodel. In the constructor of my viewmodel I pass a list of IObservable messages and subscribe to them through a simple class sitting outide of my viewmodel and view

Outside class

```
{
     viewModel =
            new ViewModelClass(
                responseHandler.AsObservable());

     viewModel.PropertyChanged += ViewModel_PropertyChanged;
 }

 private void ViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
 {

     if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ViewModelClass.MyProperty))
     {
         // Error here
         view = new MyViewClass() { DataContext = viewModel };

     }
 }
```

In the view model constructor

```
        subscription = receiveMessages.Subscribe(MessageReceived);

        private void MessageReceived(GvsMessage message)
        {
            MyProperty = true;

        }
```

On receiving a message I want to create my view not before that. Although the viewmodel is created before to handle property change etc

The problem is that I get "the calling thread must be sta because many ui components require this". Could someone please help

Comment: We need more info as you have MT (Multi-Threading) in here. We don't need detailed example just something that we could understand how your application is built.

Comment: The Outside class sits in a thread and that is the reason I am not able to change a view (create a view etc) in the ViewModel_PropertyChanged. I tried a hack to put a timer to check if my property has changed and it works. But what what be a nice way of doing it? Creating an event also gives the same problem

Comment: OK, your `View`s need to be created in the `Main UI Thread`. All the data processing could be done in the `Background Thread` otherwise `WPF` won't like it, because if you create an `UserControl` in a non-UI Thread, that thread is the owner of the object it created.

Comment: I tried creating the view in Main thread but I don't want to show it until I receive the message. Even if I show the view in ViewModel_PropertyChanged I get the error. I tried Invoke, Event but nothing works except I have to poll in the main thread

Comment: From what I can understand is you need to create a view model in another thread and then subscribe to the event on your view model, let's call it `Loaded` then you have to use `Dispatcher` to raise that loaded event so it is the same thread raising it. I can whip out  an example for you if you want.

Comment: Could you please do an example. I tried Dispatcher using Application.Current but its null

Comment: Have you had any luck?

Comment: Yes. I found a workaround. Will post an answer

Answer (score 0):

As we spoke in the comments you need to use a `Dispatcher` which can be acquired from different parts of the app.
To initialize the dispatcher you can use this snippet:

```
protected static Dispatcher _d;
if (Application.Current != null)
{
   _d = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
}
else
{
   _d = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
}
```

**Explanation:**
The first dispatcher is done when the application has `UnitTests` when you run the tests this dispatcher will not be null,
The second one is the current `Dispatcher` used by your application.
After you have this in your code when initializing your `VM` now you can send messages `Actions`, `Events` to the UI Thread.
I have a little method just for that:

```
public static void UIThread(Action action)
    {
        if (_d == null)
        {
            if (Application.Current != null)
            {
                _d = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
            }
            else
            {
                _d = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
            }
        }
        _d.Invoke(action);
    }
```

This function will accept lambda, like so:

```
UIThread(() =>
        {
            Processing = true;
            Message = "Working ...";
            //in your case you would raise the Loaded event here
        });
```

This way you `EventHandler` in your view will have no problem showing that view.
If you need any more info let us know.
HTH

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by creating the view and the viewmodel in the constructor. In the propertychanged event I just set a property IsVisible to 'true' binds the window visibility

```
<Window.Visibility>
    <Binding Path="IsVisible" Converter="{StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}" Mode="TwoWay"/>
</Window.Visibility>
```