# Custom Busy overlay on WPF WizardControl using async await

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I need load a overlay on a WPF wizardcontrol. I am using a busyIndicator tool from the wpf extended tooklit.

The code for async await works but the gui thread locks . I am trying add a please wait message when the await calls the function

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
         BusyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
         BusyIndicator.IsEnabled = true;
         BusyIndicator.BusyContent = "Please wait while Site is provisioned";

                            await Task.Run(() =>
                           {
                              LongRunningFunction();
                           });

         BusyIndicator.IsBusy=false;
        }
```

The XAML for the BusyIndicator is as below.

```
<xctk:BusyIndicator x:Name="BusyIndicator" IsBusy="False"  BusyContent="Please Wait">

</xctk:BusyIndicator>
```

The LonRunningFunction is a Webservice call which does not update the UI only returns a Bool  value

```
public static bool LongRunningFunction(string URL)
        {

            bool IsPresent = CallWebservice()
           return IsPresent;
        }
```

Issue

1)  The BusyIndicator does not seem to fire before the async call instead it seems to be fire when the LongRunning task completes

2) What is the correct  process to call a gui overlay when async and await is used.

Comment: Have you tried using `ThreadPool` instead of await? The trouble is then that if you are manipulating any UI elements in that longRunningTask you need to use dispatcher, [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37483878/2029607) is how you can use it in your code.

Comment: @XAMlMAX He *is* using the thread pool.  `Task.Run` schedules the work in a thread pool thread.

Comment: Without seeing `LongRunningFunction` there's no way to know why the code isn't working.  Clearly it's doing *something* it shouldn't, but we have no way of knowing what.

Comment: The function does not update the UI instead it only returns a bool

Comment: Ah thanks @Servy I never used `Task.Run` before. would it be because op is using `async` and `await`? It looks to me like the compiler is optimizing the code because of that making the whole body as a separate thread task. If you put a break point on `InEnabled = true` which thread you're in?

Comment: It seems to be on the same thread. Can you give me an example using Threads instead as you suggested

Comment: @user1339913 You've just shown a method that does literally nothing but call *another* thread.  You need to provide enough code to reproduce your issue.  You haven't.  You also don't want to be using threads explicitly, you just need to be using the tools that you have properly.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Such an "optimization" wouldn't be a legal refactor, so no, it can't do that.  Your suggestion that the entire TPL and a core language feature must be broken, rather than the OP simply doing something that he shouldn't, is not a reasonable assumption to make given that the OP isn't even showing a complete example.

Comment: @user1339913 have you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I tackled the problem with asynchronous calls.
**Context:**
Here I am using `MvvM` to show you good practice when working with `WPF`

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Threading;
class VM
    {
        Dispatcher _dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        //Time consuming operation
        private void LongTask()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            //in here if you need to send something to the UI thread like an event use it like so:
            _dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                //some code here to invoke an event
                if (ComponentsLoaded != null)
                    ComponentsLoaded(this, new EventArgs { });
            }));
        }

        private ICommand _command;
        //This is the command to be used instead of click event handler
        public ICommand Command
        {
            get { return _command; }
            private set { _command = value; }
        }
        //method associated with ICommand
        void commandMethod(object parameter)
        {
            Busy = true;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(multiThreadTask));
            Busy = false;
        }
        //the task to be started on another thread
        void multiThreadTask(object parameter)
        {
            LongTask();
        }

        public event EventHandler ComponentsLoaded;
    }
```

This is what I use when working with multiple threads in WPF.
You can still use this in the code-behind just instantiate the `Dispatcher` and you're good to go.
If you need any more info just let us know. HTH